# This is my JSON data and trying to acces this data and insert to the mysql

Tags: php, json

```
    {
    "gstin":"29AAHCS4690J1ZQ",
    "fp":"072017",
    "b2b":[
      {
         "ctin":"01AAACJ4126D1ZE",
         "cfs":"Y",
         "inv":[
            {
               "itms":[
                  {
                     "num":1,
                     "itc":{
                        "tx_cs":0,
                        "elg":"ip",
                        "tx_i":112.5
                     },
                     "itm_det":{
                        "csamt":0,
                        "rt":18,
                        "txval":625,
                        "iamt":112.5
                     }
                  }
               ],
               "val":738,
               "inv_typ":"R",
               "flag":"N",
               "updby":"S",
               "pos":"29",
               "idt":"31-07-2017",
               "rchrg":"N",
               "cflag":"U",
               "inum":"FL-17000069",

    "chksum":"4d3e41facf5002f418e1ac605d9888d74ee21652e19de6db624fc7106e3c5866"
            }
         ]
      },


{
         "ctin":"29AACFI3027K1ZC",
         "cfs":"Y",
         "inv":[
            {
               "itms":[
                  {
                     "num":1800,
                     "itc":{
                        "elg":"ip",
                        "tx_c":171.59,
                        "tx_s":171.59
                     },
                     "itm_det":{
                        "samt":171.59,
                        "rt":18,
                        "txval":1906.5,
                        "camt":171.59
                     }
                  }
               ],
               "val":2250,
               "inv_typ":"R",
               "flag":"N",
               "updby":"S",
               "pos":"29",
               "idt":"06-07-2017",
               "rchrg":"Y",
               "cflag":"U",
               "inum":"0042",
               "chksum":"aa1187a2bb7d6098c39c4c992bd391ab7fd59e7eeefcea5b91fc9881ba4423d8"
            }
         ]
      }
    ]
    }
```

The above code is in JSON and I am accessing this in the following way as shown below

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";


$db = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=item", $username, $password);
$jsondata = file_get_contents('data.json');
$data  = json_decode($jsondata, true);
$stmt = $db->prepare("insert into itc(tx_cs, elg) values(? , ?)");
var_dump($data);
// echo $data;
foreach($data as $row){
$stmt->bindParam(1, $row['tx_cs']);
$stmt->bindParam(2, $row['elg']);
$stmt->execute();

 }
  ?>
```

After executing insert statement I am getting just null in mysql any solution for this. If I trying to insert getting illegal string "tx_cs" if there any alternative to access nested JSON data. and also I want to know the how the array indexes Thanks in advance.

This is var_dump Result                                                                           `array(4) { ["gstin"]=> string(15) "29AAHCS4690J1ZQ" ["fp"]=> string(6) "072017" ["b2b"]=> array(59) { [0]=> array(3) { ["ctin"]=> string(15) "01AAACJ4126D1ZE" ["cfs"]=> string(1) "Y" ["inv"]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(11) { ["itms"]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(3) { ["num"]=> int(1) ["itc"]=> array(3) { ["tx_cs"]=> int(0) ["elg"]=> string(2) "ip" ["tx_i"]=> float(112.5) } ["itm_det"]=> array(4) { ["csamt"]=> int(0) ["rt"]=> int(18) ["txval"]=> int(625) ["iamt"]=> float(112.5) } } } ["val"]=> int(738) ["inv_typ"]=> string(1) "R" ["flag"]=> string(1) "N" ["updby"]=> string(1) "S" ["pos"]=> string(2) "29" ["idt"]=> string(10) "31-07-2017" ["rchrg"]=> string(1) "N" ["cflag"]=> string(1) "U" ["inum"]=> string(11) "FL-17000069" ["chksum"]=> string(64)`

Comment: I am getting 0 value in these fields.

Comment: what result show in your `var_dump` output.

Comment: json seems wrong missing `}]` at the end. Check on https://jsonlint.com/:-

Comment: updated result see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to go to the `itms` array to get your desired keys, you will need a second foreach

```
foreach($data['b2b'] as $inner){
    foreach( $inner['inv'][0]['itms'] as $row){
       $stmt->bindParam(1, $row['itc']['tx_cs']);
       $stmt->bindParam(2, $row['itc']['elg']);
    $stmt->execute();
     }
}
```

or:

```
foreach($data['b2b'] as $inner){
        $stmt->bindParam(1, $inner['inv'][0]['itms'][0]['itc']['tx_cs']);
        $stmt->bindParam(2, $inner['inv'][0]['itms'][0]['itc']['elg']);
        $stmt->execute();
 }
```

Comment: bro getting this warning and error                                                                    Notice: Undefined index: inv in C:\xampp\xampp\htdocs\ExcelDownload\jsonimport.php on line 21

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\xampp\htdocs\ExcelDownload\jsonimport.php on line 21

Comment: Bro I want to access and insert the next  " itm_det" and also                                                     "val":738,
               "inv_typ":"R",
               "flag":"N",   so on

Comment: then you do  `$stmt->bindParam(3, $inner['inv'][0]['val']);` etc

Comment: how to insert ctin and cfs

Comment: its on the same principle `$stmt->bindParam(4, $inner['ctin ']);`, you should seriously learn the language before you dive into code

Comment: bro if tx_cs comes first and elg or vice versa then what to do

Comment: the best option will be to learn the language, read the documentation

Answer (score 0):

Use following code, this work perfectly:

```
 $db = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=item", $username, $password);
    $data  = json_decode($jsondata, true);

    $sql = 'INSERT INTO itc (tx_cs, elg) VALUES ';
    $insertQuery = array();
    $insertData = array();
    $n = 0;
    foreach($data['b2b'] as $inner){
        foreach( $inner['inv'][0]['itms'] as $row){
            $insertQuery[] = '(:tx_cs' . $n . ', :elg' . $n . ')';
            $insertData['tx_cs' . $n] = $row['itc']['tx_cs'];
            $insertData['elg' . $n] = $row['itc']['elg'];
            $n++;
        }
    }

    if (!empty($insertQuery)) {
        $sql .= implode(', ', $insertQuery);
        $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->execute($insertData);
    }
```

With this approach you just run your query one time and have good performance of I/O

Comment: Bro, getting    Undefined index: tx_cs

Comment: is the sample json full version? if you can upload this file in the remote server, this code working with sample json that you have in your post